# MPAndroidChart PieChart is not showing Markerview

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I am implementing Piechart where I want to show Markerview on slice selection, as it is in Barchart. So I set a Markerview for Piechart.

```
mChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(this, R.layout.custom_marker_view);
    mChart.setMarkerView(mv);
    mChart.getMarkerView().setEnabled(true);
```

I don't want to customize Markerview. I am using the same Markerview as in BarChart. 
I even remove the chartValueSelectedListener.

```
//mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
```

But the markerView is not visible.

Comment: FYI... I have read the Documentation for MarkerView and implemented accordingly. While debugging  `refreshContent(Entry e, int dataSetIndex) {..}`  in myMarkerView never called. I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry this is not stated clearly in the documentation.

But the MarkerView is currently not supported for PieCharts and HorizontalBarChart. It is the only chart-type it does not work on yet.

**UPDATE**:

Since [release v2.1.4](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases) `MarkerView` is **now supported** for `PieChart` and `HorizontalBarChart` as well.

Comment: have you implemented markerview for piechart in your latest update?